# Configuring Wordpress HOME_URL and SITE_URL behind alb with ssl termination on it. Looking for possibility to use behind cloudfront

Tags: wordpress, configuration, dns, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

The main scheme is:

```
DNS(CloudFlare)->
CloudFront(fasdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net)->
Origin is ALB (alb-aws.com)->
ALB Listeners configured 80 to 443 redirect and 443 to 80 target group->
Some fargate tasks in target group.
```

Wordpress configured with efs to single database. For now with CNAME to ALB A record responding well with domain name. For me is not understandable how to configure cloudfront, because when I set CNAME on CloudFlare to cloudfront it seem's like cloudfront cant get data from ALB, because wordpress redirecting to the domain name defined in config. And DNS is pointed to cloudfront. So for me its like circle which cant be broken. WP SITE_URL and HOME_URL configured in wp-config.php with https://. Additionally added in config

```
if (strpos(*_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   *_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Is there any suggestions on it? Thanks.